# Button Movement Android

Tags: android, eclipse, button

Is it possible to let the buttons move freely? like dragging it and moving it around with your finger or accelerometer. 
Thank you very much for any advice you are willing to give me

Comment: your question is not clear. please explain what you want exactly...

Comment: I would like for an button to move freely, its not locked into a position on the linear layout.

Comment: Refactor Question and Question Title as per your requirements Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Is this what you are looking for?